# Confidence / statistical significance of empirical probability estimation

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

The empirical probability of an event can be estimated as the number of times the event occurred $E$ divided by the total number of samples $N$.

For example rolling a dice 12 times if we see a 6  for  3 times we can say that   $\hat p =P(x=6) = 3/12$.

How can I add in this model the confidence that I have in the estimated probability as a function of the samples size?

For example if $N = \infty$  then the confidence should be $1$ while if $N\sim 0$ the confidence should be 0 .

The main application I am looking for is to not overestimate the probability of certain events that may only be due to the small sample size. 
For example if you roll a dice twice and you get 2 times 6 you do now want to say that the probability of 6 is 100%.

A current simple solution that I am using is $\hat p = E / (N + K)$ where $K$ is predefined value. I am wondering if a better solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not as easy as it seems. When rolling a dice or flipping a coin:

- the parameter is $p$: theoretical probability to get a 6
- you known $X$: the number of 6s on $N$ trials
- you want to estimate $p$.

The distribution of $X$ is a binomial distribution $B(N,p)$. What is the best estimator for $p$?

The notion of the best estimator is easier in the Bayesian approach: the estimator with least expected squared error is the conditional mean $\hat p=E(p|X)$ . With a uniform prior it is $\hat p=\frac{X+1}{N+2}$. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair. You can calculate this for the prior that you want. With a Beta prior with parameters $\alpha,\beta$ it is $\hat p=\frac{X+\alpha}{N+\alpha+\beta}$, which is equivalent to the frequentist estimator having seen $\alpha$ 6s on $\alpha+\beta$ trials before. Your simple solution is the special case $\alpha=0$.

In the frequentist approach, the notion of the best estimator is nothing simple. The estimator used is usually $\hat p=\frac{X}{N}$. You can compute confidence intervals. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Now, from a machine learning point of view, I recommend analysing the sentence:

> The main application I am looking for is to not overestimate the
>   probability of certain events that may only be due to the small sample
>   size.

How do you quantify the consequences of overestimation? This kind of analysis leads to find the best estimator for your specific purpose. You can look at it for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a binomial distribution of $N$ trials and you estimate the success probability $p$ using $\hat{p} = E/N$.

As covered by the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29641/75085) you can derive a standard error for $\hat{p}$ equal to $\sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{N}}$.