# Confidence interval of X occuring given Y samples of S space

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

If I found X number of E events given Y unique samples of a known sample space S, where:

- Y is much smaller than is smaller than S
- E is a binary event

Can I say that event X has a probability and provide a confidence interval for that estimated probability?

For example, given a sample space of 10^4 black and white marbles in a bag. If I pulled 100 of those marbles and 10 of them were white, what could I determine about the probability of choosing a white marble out of the original/unsampled 10^4 bag of marbles?

This seems related to "[Confidence / statistical significance of empirical probability estimation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/317239/confidence-statistical-significance-of-empirical-probability-estimation)" but I know the sample space size.

Comment: Could you illustrate this with a real-life example?

Comment: @Tim add real-life example with marbles as suggested