# how to estimate the number of known words in a text

Tags: estimation, proportion, small-sample, delta-method

I would like to estimate the proportion of known words in a text from a sample of tested words, where a subject answers if they know the meaning or not, and the frequency of how often they appear in a text. I want to know the proportion of total words, not unique words, so if "dog" appears in a text 10 times, it counts as 10 words and not 1.

For example, I have a text where words appear 1, 5, or 20 times. I randomly sample and test 50 words in each group with results:

100 words that each appeared 20 times, 80% correct

250 words, each appeared 5 times, 50% correct

1000 words, each appeared once, 20% correct

This would be (100*20*0.8 + 250*5*0.5 + 1000*1*0.2) / (100*20 + 250*5 + 1000*1) = 0.57, so around 57% of words are known, but I would like to also know a standard error of that estimate. We can assume that in each group, there is a different proportion of known words.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I find your procedure quite complicated for a fairly straightforward problem. I can only guess that what you are describing omitted some details that would clarify it. I also don't fully understand why you group the words by frequencies and consider the groups together, it seems quite arbitrary.

Regardless if you want to group the words or look at all the words together, the answer would be similar. You can think of each of the words as a [Bernoulli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) random variable with probability $p$ of it being known. This means making an assumption that all the words (total, or within a group) have the same $p$, and follow the same distribution. In such a case, the variance of the variable is equal to $p(1-p)$, and the [standard error is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29641/standard-error-for-the-mean-of-a-sample-of-binomial-random-variables) $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}$ where $n$ is the number of unique words (all or per group, depending how you calculate it). To aggregate the groups, you would use [pooled](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194774/combining-two-estimates/194798#194798) estimates, what you already figured out.

Finally, "understanding" a word may mean different things. One thing is understanding without context, what you seem to be measuring. Another thing is that the meaning of the word can often be guessed from nearby words. There is also a broader social context, for example as me, you might not know what the German word *"gesperrten"* means, but if you look at [this news article](https://www.welt.de/politik/ausland/article242232921/Twitter-entsperrt-Account-von-Ex-Praesident-Trump-aber-der-will-angeblich-nicht-zurueck.html), and the sentence *"Twitter hat den seit Anfang 2021 gesperrten Account von Ex-Präsident Donald Trump wiederhergestellt."* you could guess that is is something meaning that they locked his account. So "understanding" doesn't necessarily happen in the void.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe it is too complicated, what would be an easier procedure? They are grouped by frequency because higher frequency words are more likely to be known that lower frequency words, also if you won't group them you will be overtesting words that are almost never used and undertesting high frequency words that are most important for comprehension. The proportion of total words known in a text is an important metric for comprehension of the text, so the goal is not to estimate a size of a vocabulary

Comment: @rep_ho I meant mostly the grouping part, but I may be missing important details of your scenario.

Comment: Maybe we don;t understand each other, I am sorry I can't explain it better. If you know 98% of words in a text (total words, not unique words), you are supposed to be able to comprehend it with ease. so Shakespeare used 30k words in his work, but 15k only once and 5k most common words gives you 95% coverage of total words used (i made that up). That's why they are grouped by frequency. And that 'coverage' is what I want to estimate, and not how many from the 30k you know